# How do I set a name_scope in a graph to be removed from main graph in python

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm trying to organize my TensorBoard graph such that a certain component is automatically placed on the side when I first initiate TensorBoard.

[image]

I want the `save` node to be on the right, like this:

[image]

I can right click on `save` in the graph itself, But I'd rather have it waiting for me this way when I get there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't currently possible, although we are planning to do this as part of a broader push to improve the graph visualizer in the next few months.
If you want, you can file a GitHub issue for tracking (but we will do this either way).

Comment: Any status on the implementation of this feature? Maybe you could link the GitHub issue.